# Simple notation question about independent sigma algebras

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let the random variables $X$, $Y$ be independent, i.e. for the sigma algebra generated by those variables holds $\sigma(X,Y) = \sigma(X)\sigma(Y)$.

If $ \omega \in \sigma(X,Y)$, then we have also $\omega \in \sigma(X)\sigma(Y)$.

My question: How can I move on from this? So $\omega \in \sigma(X)\sigma(Y)$. Can one say that $\omega \in \sigma(X)$ and $\omega \in \sigma(Y)$ holds?

More specific: what can I "expect" from the fact that $\omega$ lies in the product of two sigma algebras? What does this say about the properties of the single element $\omega$?

Thanks in advance for further explanations! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, of course you can't say $\omega \in \sigma(X)$.  $\sigma(X,Y)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by sets $X^{-1}(a,b)$ and $Y^{-1}(a,b)$
for all open intervals $(a,b)$.
So it contains countable unions of countable intersections of such sets (and more complicated things too).

Comment: Thank you! Is there a possibility to simplifie it in any way? I have the problem that I have an indicator function $1_{A \in \sigma(X,Y)}$ and for the proof it would be necessary to somehow split this one indicatorfunction in two regarding always one sigma field $\sigma(X)$, $\sigma(Y)$... Is there a possibility for this?

Comment: No, there isn't.  You can have some very complicated combination of countably many members of $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$.